# Cannot connect to PostgreSQL Server 10 with JDBC

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, postgresql-10

I can connect with pgAdmin but not with JDBC, what I am doing wrong?

[image]

JDBC:

Approach #1

```
String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/microlms360";

Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("user","microlms360app");
props.setProperty("password","p0stgr@s");
props.setProperty("ssl","true");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
```

Approach #2

```
String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/microlms360?user=microlms360app&password=p0stgr@s&ssl=false";
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url)) {
    boolean res = conn.createStatement().execute("SELECT 1");
    System.out.println(res);
}
```

Result are the same in both cases (I've tried `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` as the hostname. In vain.)

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:8648', transport: 'socket'
Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to 127.0.0.1:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:280)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:454)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:256)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at iex.Main.main(Main.java:16)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:70)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:91)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192)
    ... 7 more
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:8648', transport: 'socket'
```

According to this [postgresql.org blog](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/) I am using the latest driver

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
  <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
  <version>42.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

UPD: postgress process is actually listening, so "nothing listen the port" is not the case [image: postgress process is actually listening, so "nothing listen the port" is not the case]

Comment: Your new screenshot suggests it may be listening on `WS-LV-CP2320.eleks-software.local` port 5432, that doesn't mean it is listening on localhost port 5432. Could you add the output of `netstat -ano`?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing listening on localhost port 5432 on the machine the Java application is running, or it is actively blocked by a firewall. The error message *"java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect"* is from Java's low-level socket, and leaves no doubt that it can't connect.

Either PgAdmin4 is not blocked by a firewall, or your screenshot from PgAdmin4 is from a different machine, or you are connecting to PgAdmin4 running on a different host where PostgreSQL is running on localhost port 5432.